How to insert � (U+FFFD) without getting the error "String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence."
I would like to insert the replacement character (�), unfortunately I get an error that this char is invalid. Indeed, this is the replacement character...
But what if I would like to insert it without issue?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("fontfallback",
    {
      "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf;",
      "Symbola:mode=harf;",
      "NotoNaskhArabic:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifHebrew:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifDevanagari:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifTamil:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifTibetan:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  RawFeature={fallback=fontfallback}
]

\begin{document}
Hey �
\end{document}

I get the same error this this MRE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hey �
\end{document}

Here with LuaLaTeX:
$ latexmk -lualatex test.tex 
Rc files read:
  /etc/LatexMk
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'test.aux'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "test.tex"'
------------
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (./test.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.5 Hey 
      �
? 


can you get that error with fonts in texlive? without the font load I get no error just the expected warning latin mdern doesn't have that charecter but with it I get font not found errors (and i don't wish to install a bunch of noto fonts just to test this)

I've added a MRE.

you will have to update your system. In texlive 2023 and 2024 it works.

@UlrikeFischer Damned... I have Ubuntu 22.04 and I am not sure what my CI uses.

you can try the input Hey ^^^^fffd.

@UlrikeFischer Tested on 24.04, I have indeed no errors :(

Checking with texlive 2022 on overleaf this works without error
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hey ^^^^fffd
\end{document}

The original form with an explicit �  works in later texlive releases.

What is that magic?

^^ (in classic tex, extended to ^^^^ and ^^^^^^ in luatex and xetex) allows characters to be entered by hex number rather than keyboard input.  You can use it more or less anywhere eg ^^5c^^64ocumentclass{article}  will work as the first line, if you feel like confusing people. @nowox

When the error is issued is it by luaotfload? or a latex2e class?

by luatex reading the input file (as far as I can remember) the ^^^^ syntax parses as a character token so for any processing after the initital "eyes" of tex, there is no difference between using ^^^^ and using the character so no lua or latex package gets to see the ^^^^ @yannisl

You can also use \symbol{"FFFD}.

you can but only when typesetting, the ^^^^ notation produces a character  so can also be used in \typeout or pdf bookmarks or even command names such as \^^^^fffd  which is \�
